# Forcing MATLAB to use `single` precision as default?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to force MATLAB to use `single` precision as default precision?

I have a MATLAB code, whose output I need to compare to C code output, and C code is written exclusively using `floats`, no `doubles` allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

Longer answer: In most cases, you can get around this by setting your initial variables to single. Once that's done, that type will (almost always) propagate down through your code. (cf. [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/170061) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/8727-single-precision-by-default-lots-of-auxiliary-variables-to-cast) thread on MathWorks).

So, for instance, if you do something like:

```
>> x = single(magic(4));
>> y = double(6);
>> x * y

ans =

  4×4 single matrix

    96    12    18    78
    30    66    60    48
    54    42    36    72
    24    84    90     6
```

MATLAB keeps the answer in the lower precision. I have occasionally encountered functions, both built-in and from the FileExchange, that recast the output to be a double, so you will want to sprinkle in the occasional `assert` statement to keep things honest during your initial debugging (or better yet put the assertion as the first lines of any sub-functions you write to check the critical inputs), but this should get you 99% of the way there.

Comment: Thanks. My code is not so small, it would take too long to go and change every MATLAB variable to `single`. So currently, no solution for me. Maybe change my C code instead, to use typedef for floats, `typedef float_t double;` and then verify against MATLAB.

Comment: That's my point, though. You don't have to change every variable, just the key ones. In the short example above, Once `x` is set to single, all operations on `x` are implicitly single, even if subsequent operands are doubles. I do something similar when I want to do GPU operations. I set my image to class `gpuArray`, and then all subsequent operations happen on the GPU without my having to add any further specific declarations, with the results also being class `gpuArray`.

Comment: I see. In my case it's MATLAB `filter` and `butter` calls. Not sure if I can know what's goding on inside those.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert any object `A` to single precision using `A=single(A);`

[The Mathworks forums](http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/47142-how-to-set-matlab-precision-to-single#answer_57613) show that
in your case: `system-specific('precision','8');` should do it. Try this in the console or add at the top of your script.

Comment: `system-specific` does not exist. What exists is `system_dependent`. However, it accepts only 24, 53 or 64. I tried `system_dependent('setprecision',24)`, and the MATLAB output is exactly the same as before, so - it does not work.

Comment: I am a huge fan of Yair Altman and [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/) from which this answer ultimately derives, but they are just that: undocumented and subject to change. You have to be careful relying on any undocumented feature that's more than a few versions old.

Comment: @craigim: Can't help it, I do not have Matlab on this computer and I remembered where to find it... but this might still be useful for people working on old versions (surprisingly many people! OK I guess not that surprising since new licenses are crazy expensive)

Comment: I get it. I use his undocumented tips and tricks all the time and most of them have proven to be surprisingly stable over time. Just make sure that whenever you do, you add a comment to your code that that's what you did with a url link to the blog post you got it from. If you go to the [original post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function/) for the `feature` and `system_dependent` functions, even he hasn't tested them all out.